# How to pass controller variable to view in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

This is my controller:

```
class MyWorksController extends AppController{
    function index(){
        $workLevel = $this->getWorkLevel();
        if($workLevel == 3){
            $recreationID = $this->getRecessId($workLevel );
            $this->set('recreationID', $recreationID);
            $this->redirect('/MyWorks/report1/');
        }
        else{ 
            $this->redirect('/MyWorks/report2/');
        }     
    }
    function report1(){}

    function report2(){}
}
```

I want to send $recreationID value to my view page's form, in the following way:

```
echo $form->create('FishingTimeAllocations', array('tmt:validate'=>'true', 'action'=>'index', 'recreationID '=>$recreationID ));?>
```

However, I was unsuccessful in doing so, and the error I keep getting is this:

```
Undefined variable: recreationID
```

What is the problem in my code and what is the correct way to get my desired thing done?

CakePHP version 1.2, PHP version 5.2, MySQL version 5.1.36. (I'm aware I'm running old versions of these items of software - nothing I can do about that at the moment).

Comment: Maybe the answer is as simple as your `set` isn't being called because your $worklevel is not equal to 3?

Comment: @AgRizzo Or maybe, you're overlooking a simpler and obvious fact that if $workLevel is not equal 3, it will redirect to some other page. Basic if-else logic. Thanks, but no thanks, for your comment. :P

Comment: And if it _is_ 3 then it will redirect too, that's pretty basic as well. So you get what is the expected behavior, view variables do not persist between requests.

Comment: Look at your question header. Your question is different from what you need. you where asking how to show variable from controller to view. of-course if you want to pass you variable to action you need to do it as parameter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can not send variables using `set()` to other actions. If you want to use the variable to another page (view file), you need to do it with these two possible ways:

1. set in session and then use it.
2. pass as url parameter.

**Note:-** In these two way session way is more secure.

Comment: This. Make recreationId an argument of your report1 endpoint and pass it in the redirect.

Comment: Probably this is what I'm looking for, cause among all others, you seemed to understand my problem pretty accurately. I think I'll go for url parameter instead of session as it is most likely to serve my purpose. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

This actually doesn't work cause `$recreationID` variable is set for your `index()` view.
If you want have this variable in `report1()` you should do it this way:

```
function index() {
    ...
    $this->redirect('/MyWorks/report1/' . $recreationID);
    ...
}

function report1($recreationID){
    $this->set('recreationID', $recreationID);
}
```

It is also possible to accomplish with Session.

Comment: No. You got it wrong. Take a closer look at my form in the view. **The index() method does not belong to the MyWorks controller, but a different controller named FishingTimeAllocations**. I want to use this `$recreationID` in some other page, which I can access through the `index()` method of the `FishingTimeAllocations` controller. Please go through it again.

Comment: Sorry, but then your question is unclear. You gave us only MyWorksController and I can't help with code which I don't see. If you want pass this variable somewhere else you can do this the same way, through URL param or through Session. All you need you'll find in Cake doc.